# How to convert a string in array to number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion

Suppose that I need to convert the content of these arrays below to number

```
const a = ['1']

const b = ['1', '2', '3']
```

To do that, I have tried these methods below to no avail. The content of the arrays are still of string type.

```
Number(a)

b.map(Number)
```

I have searched in the documentary of [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/number) and (for me) those methods should sufficient to do the job. Did I miss something in understanding how `Number` works or I simply used wrong solution for the problem?

Comment: `b.map(Number)` does what you want. I guess you forgot to assign the result of it to something (`const newThing = b.map(Number)`). (`Number(a)` won't work because `a` is an array and not a string.)

Comment: `a` is not a string.

Comment: @CherryDT Thanks, the problem does stand from me not assign the result to something

Comment: As for `Number(a)` I realized it's a mistake, should use `a[0]` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

So the solutions you need is:

```
const a = ['1']

const b = ['1', '2', '3']

const newA = a.map(Number);
const newB = b.map(Number);

console.log(newA) // [1]
console.log(newB) // [1, 2, 3]
```

As a map create a new array, variable a and b still got the same values.

Answer (score 0):

use this to convert array string to array number

```
a =  a.map(d => Number(d))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const b = ['1', '2', '3'];

const nums = b.map(Number)

const nums2 = b.map((num) => +num)

console.log(nums, nums2)
```